# UWP listview mutiple ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

How can I have my `ListView` have multiple `ItemContainerStyle`?

```
<ListView x:Name="SongsListView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
        <!--<Style TargetType="ListViewItemPresenter">
            <Setter Property="SelectedPointerOverBackground" Value="White" />
        </Style>-->
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're trying to add multiple styles doesn't make any sense. You can't have more than one `Style` applied on a control at the same time. There is no point in doing that. However you can ask UWP to apply **one** of the many `Style`s programmatically.

UWP, just like WPF, supports `ItemContainerStyleSelector`. This is a simple class that allows you to select a `Style` based on some condition or procedure. You may check one working example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/535a00e6-7f02-469d-a06f-4ce2478c73a6/uwp-itemcontainerstyleselector?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: I still think adding multiple styles makes sense because I am changing the style from different component of my control.

Comment: A `Style` inside `ItemContainerStyle` **must** target the type that is produced by the  item generator of your control. In case of `ListView`, this is a `ListViewItem`. If you want to target some specific property of a child component inside your items, you can do that by adding anonymous `Style`s inside the `Resources` section of your main `Style`.

Comment: Do you mean override it? I have put that under the `UserControl.Resource` but it seems not working.

Comment: And what is the difference between StyleSelector and a OneWay Converter?

Comment: @SeakyLuo If you need to switch `ItemContainerStyle` depending on the component, use `ItemContainerStyleSelector`, you can create a class to inherit it and write the judgment conditions in it, just like the example provided by @dotNET .  `ItemContainerStyleSelector` can switch different `ItemContainerStyle` according to the data, and Converter can convert the data into other types in `DataTemplate`, such as changing color according to age.